# populate cell in mastersheet with text that changes from worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

1st post 
I have a worksheet where an employee’s name (John Doe) is input by user in cell `B2`.

Then I run a `VBA` code to rename the worksheet to the name that was input in `B2`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Specify the target cell whose entry shall be the sheet tab name.
    If Target.Address <> "$B$2" Then Exit Sub
        'If the target cell is empty (contents cleared) then do not change the shet name
    If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    'If the length of the target cell's entry is greater than 31 characters, disallow the entry.
    If Len(Target.Value) > 31 Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet tab names cannot be greater than 31 characters in length." & vbCrLf & _
        "You entered " & Target.Value & ", which has " & Len(Target.Value) & " characters.", , "Keep it under 31 characters"
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Sheet tab names cannot contain the characters /, \, [, ], *, ?, or :.
    'Verify that none of these characters are present in the cell's entry.
    Dim IllegalCharacter(1 To 7) As String, i As Integer
    IllegalCharacter(1) = "/"
    IllegalCharacter(2) = "\"
    IllegalCharacter(3) = "["
    IllegalCharacter(4) = "]"
    IllegalCharacter(5) = "*"
    IllegalCharacter(6) = "?"
    IllegalCharacter(7) = ":"
    For i = 1 To 7
        If InStr(Target.Value, (IllegalCharacter(i))) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "You used a character that violates sheet naming rules." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Please re-enter a sheet name without the ''" & IllegalCharacter(i) & "'' character.", 48, "Not a possible sheet name !!"
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    'Verify that the proposed sheet name does not already exist in the workbook.
    Dim strSheetName As String, wks As Worksheet, bln As Boolean
    strSheetName = Trim(Target.Value)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not wks Is Nothing Then
        bln = True
    Else
        bln = False
        Err.Clear
    End If

    'If the worksheet name does not already exist, name the active sheet as the target cell value.
    'Otherwise, advise the user that duplicate sheet names are not allowed.
    If bln = False Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = strSheetName
    Else
        MsgBox "There is already a sheet named " & strSheetName & "." & vbCrLf & _
        "Please enter a unique name for this sheet."
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

This part works great. Worksheet is now named John Doe.

Now I want the sheetname derived from B2 (`John Doe`) to populate a cell in the mastersheet. Have written a simple if statement in the `mastersheet =IF('John Doe'!B2="","",'John Doe'!B2)`

Now I need a new worksheet, so I copy John Doe and paste at end of worksheet, input Jimmy John in copied worksheet cell B2 to rename the worksheet. Return to mastersheet and now need to populate a new cell with worksheet named Jimmy John.

So I guess the question is how can I dynamically change the formula `=IF('John Doe'!B2="","",'John Doe'!B2)` on the mastersheet to use whatever text is in the worksheet cell B2. I thought of a commandbutton using find and replace, but am not experienced enough to make it work.

Comment: If you first add the formula and the sheetname gets changed later with VBA like `Worksheets("John Doe").Name = "Jimmy John"` Excel should automatically change the formula to the new sheet name. At least I tried it and it worked, so I cannot reproduce your issue. Can you show your code?

Comment: Or probably in the Worksheet_Change() event, which changes the name of the worksheet, you are disabling events? In this case write `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end. Or something similar? Just guessing.

Comment: If I use your code and type in cell B2, Excel changes the formula automatically to the new sheet name. This is the default behavior of Excel: If you rename a sheet, then all formulas are adapted automatically. • The issue is that you copy the sheet. Obviously the old sheet remains `John Doe` and also the formula. You are changing the **new** sheets name which doesn't have a reference in your mastersheet (the reference remains to `John Doe`). How do you copy the sheet? Manually or with a macro? You will need a macro (button) that adds a new formula to the mastersheet referencing the new sheet.

Comment: Thanks Peh... I copy the sheet manually. I believe the macro method will work.  Can you suggest what the macro would look like?

Comment: @hspeckiii you would need to write the desired formula with `.Range("A1").Formula = "=IF('" & strSheetName & "'!B2="","",'" & strSheetName & "'!B2)"` into a desired cell `A1`. Where `strSheetName` is a string containing the name of the newly added sheet.

Comment: Peh... Thanks for the code. Have tried to create a macro using this code, but I need some additional hand holding. cant seem to make this work. my project is due soon, so any other help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @hspeckiii The problem is we can only help you so far that you can solve the issue yourself, we cannot do the work for you. And because your question is not very specific and too broad to give a detailed answer we can only give hints and show how an approach could look like. If you ask a broad question the answer will always be broad too (because we don't know the details). If you tell it doesn't work nobody knows what you did and what errors you get, so how can you expect help if you don't tell what's wrong? This site is not good in guiding someone it is meant to ask a very specific question.

Comment: And let's say (that's not meant to be rude, but I just have to say it) nobody here is responsible that you got a deadline for your project. Most people here react somehow allergically on people talking about deadlines and making pressure. If you cannot solve it in time you probably need to hire someone who can do it for you. Free help needs people who offer their free time and they don't care about deadlines.

Comment: Peh.. I have solved my problem. So you and the members of this board will know, my comment about the deadline was not intended to come across as pressure. It was simply a statement. As a newbie to VBA and this board, 'free help' is more than appreciated, it reduces learning curve, shows multiple ways to attack a problem, and (should) provide a safe harbour for one to admit ones lack of knowledge and expertise. Most people (myself included) tend to forget what it was like when learning something new.

Comment: Any rate... really do appreciate your time and effort here

Answer (score 0):

You can use INDIRECT() formula to solve this problem.

Write in B1 the Name of the Worksheet, if possible without spaces (e.g. *John_Doe* or *JohnDoe*). Then in another place write the follwoing formula:

```
=IF(
   INDIRECT(B1&"!A2")="";
    "";
   INDIRECT(B1&"!A2"))
```

If you need the spaces (e.g. *John Doe*), the formula looks like this:

```
=IF(
   INDIRECT("'"&B1&"'!A2")="";
    "";
   INDIRECT("'"&B1&"'!A2"))
```

The formula takes the value of the cell A2 in the sheet with a name, specified in `B1`.
Whenever you change the target worksheet name somehow, you have to change the name of the sheet in `B1`. Like this:

[image]

Here you can see more about Indirect():

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261

Comment: @Peh - yup, you are right, I thought of something else first.

Comment: I think you (or me maybe) still misunderstood. I think he wants that `John Doe` in his formula `=IF('John Doe'!B2="","",'John Doe'!B2)` automatically changes if the sheet name `John Doe` changes to `Jimmy John` what it should already do automatically by default in Excel.

Comment: @Peh - indeed, this is a built-in automatic feature in Excel.

Comment: Vityata... Thanks for the reply and code. please read the post with additional information and the code already working. At the risk of ridicule from the more seasoned members, I admit that I am a novice and your code may work, bur i do not understand how to execute it.

Comment: @hspeckiii - in general, step by step explaining of the problem, as you have done really helps everyone to understand it. Cheers! :)